# Assessing the Penalties of Overparametrization when employing a k-fold cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

I am currently conducting a study using spatial occupancy models. To select the most predictive model, I am employing a k-fold cross-validation approach. I am aware of the potential pitfalls of over-parametrization, such as overfitting, and decreased interpretability.
However, I am still uncertain about how to quantify the specific penalties associated with over-parametrization in the context of my study. For instance, how would over-parametrization influence the outcomes of the k-fold cross-validation?